# How can I log out of my IAM user profile from the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to do some AWS commands, but I am on the wrong IAM user profile. So when I run the command I get this message:

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: User: arn:aws:iam::9999999999999:user/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: lambda:CreateFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:99999999999:function:zzzzzzzzzzzzzz

How can I log out of this IAM user profile, and go onto a different one which works?

I have tried clearing my .aws/credentials file and running the command again but I seem to be permanently stuck on this incorrect profile!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have credentials set as environment variables or something? The CLI tool doesn't stay "logged in" like you are implying. It picks up the credentials you have configured each time you run it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: This was it - my environment variables were configured to the wrong AWS profile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `aws configure`  and see if the credentials configured corresponding to default profile is correct or not,

Next potential point can be the user that you are using from CLI doesn't have permission to perform `create function`. Try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-awscli.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with closing my terminal.
When you open a new terminal you have to log in again with
`aws configure` command

Answer (score -1):

FIXED The environment variables were set to the wrong AWS profile